# Separate numbers from text in python

Tags: python

I have text data something like this:

```
'ABC\n',
'12.00-14.00 gm%\n',
'10.00 gm%\n',
'DEF\n',
'4000-11000 cells/cu mm.\n',
'5000 cells/cu mm\n',
'GHI\n',
'AAAA',
'40 70\n',
'83\n',
'BBB\n',
'20 40\n',
'20\n',
```

I want output like this:

```
Name  Value            Range
ABC   10.00            12.00-14.00 gm%
DEF   5000             4000-11000 cells/cu mm.
.....Same for all other values
```

I want output in table form.
How do I do it in python ?

Comment: So you always have 3 input rows that describe one output row?
What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why are there some ranges with, and some without `-`? What are those two consecutive `GHI` and `AAAA` lines, and why does `AAAA` not have a `\n`?

Comment: Please edit following the rules in: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) from the Stack Overflow Help Center.

Comment: @tobias_k This is the output from the google vision API for text documents it is so much unstructured. kindly tell me if you have any idea how to solve it.

Answer (score -2):

You can group per three items in the list and proceed as follows. Hope it helps.
for example, `'ABC\n','12.00-14.00 gm%\n','10.00 gm%\n'` will be the first group in your iteration.

```
data = ['ABC\n',
'12.00-14.00 gm%\n',
'10.00 gm%\n',
'DEF\n',
'4000-11000 cells/cu mm.\n',
'5000 cells/cu mm\n',
'GHI\n',
'AAAA',
'40 70\n',
'83\n',
'BBB\n',
'20 40\n',
'20\n']

print "Name  Value            Range"
outp = [data[i].strip() + "\t" + data[i+2].strip() + "\t" +    data[i+1].strip()+'\n' for i in range(0, len(data)-3, 3)] 
for m in outp:print m
```

Comment: This is just a code dump with no explanation, answering an unclear question.

Comment: @ Mad Physicist, too quick , I was saving the code :)